# How do I enable Video Chat in Empathy for MSN and Yahoo?

Tags: video, empathy, webcam

Video Chat is always greyed out in Empathy (Yahoo and MSN contacts have the same issue) (2.32.1), however, video chat in Skype (Beta) Works 100% perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Empathy FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#For_which_protocols_does_Empathy_support_audio_and_video_chat.3F) it only works with certain protocols:

> Currently for SIP/XMPP/Gtalk. MSN support is currently broken due to change Microsoft has done to their server, see [this blog post](http://kakaroto.homelinux.net/2010/03/amsn-0-98-2-to-be-released-without-audiovideo-support/) for more detail.